# Instrument Control Library - SerialPort Exceptions

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, dll, serial-port

I am writing a library to control some measuring instruments and today I asked myself how should I handle the Exceptions, e.g. if I have somethink like this in a class "DigitalMultimeter"

```
Public Function GetSerialNumber() As String
    Me.SerialPort.Write("SN" & vbCr)
    'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    Return SerialPort.ReadTo(vbCrLf)
 End Function
```

Should I do the try catch block here, or leave it for the customer of the library, since (afaik) the eventually exception will raise all the way up to the caller, without needing to rethrow it here, or I am wrong?

Another question is, if such a method takes a while to read the response, e.g. the instrument needs time to do some calculus or temperature needs to be adjusted, should I make it an Async Method, or leave it sync., being the consumer who decides what to do? Is this CPU-Bound or I/O Bound?

Do you maybe know an OpenSource Library or Info, which uses SerialPorts to take a look at, since I am not really sure about the best-practices using SerialPorts?

Thanks in advance
RG